# Does Asp.Net Identity worth the overhead?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm creating web applications using Asp.Net Core Identity with N-Tier architecture. Lately I've been discovering many properties of this library that I didn't know before as I need to configure the system. I'm at a point where I'm trying to learn how to customize these parts of my system rather than developing my own code.

Another thing is, in my humble opinion Authorization should be on the business layer but Authorization framework forces you to implement it in MVC layer and adds dependency to other ASP components.

It seems like this framework adds lots of overhead (like it even creates properties in DB that you don't need in the first place you have to suppress them on DbContext configs).

So my question is should I start my projects with these frameworks or should I implement thin components for these frameworks and add on as I need more functionality ? Or does the benefits worth the overhead of these frameworks ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, authorization and authentication are not business domain problems.  Ergo, the code that implements them doesn't necessarily go in the business layer.

Comment: I agree with the authentication part but If you were to change the MVC layer to SPA would you write all authorization logic again ? So I think it belongs to business domain.

Comment: Depends on what your MVC layer is doing.  If it's a web API, it won't matter.  If you're converting from a traditional ASP.NET MVC application to a SPA, you'll have to do that work anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would argue that Authorization most definitely belongs in the Business layer. 

A very simple example - I have a requirement that a user should only be able to view another users details if they are an administrator.
That is a business rule, and as such belongs in the business layer.

The presentation layer should still know these rules, not to "enforce" them, but to provide a better user experience (by not showing actions that cannot be performed and returning early from methods if it knows they will fail due to lack of authorization).

Comment: @Jack thank you for the support :) That is exactly how I think about Authorization. I'm thinking of quickly wiring up a new authorization system maybe by using some of Asp.Net Authorization source code and by leaving the parts that I don't need. Because it seems bloated to me with all attribute usage and other mechanisms that I don't wanna use. What would be your advice on that one ?

Comment: @brainoverflow98 I'd say that asp.net identity does not mean you cannot also do authorization in the business layer.

I personally do not use asp.net identity in current applications, but that's more down to using an existing legacy database and already having the framework in place to support everything it does. 
I still think attributes to define what roles can access given methods is useful, if only to speed up development as you can see at a glance who is allowed to access a given method. 
I don't think business layer arguments factor into asp.net identity, as they can work in tandem.

Comment: @Jack yes it is easy to set-up for simple authentication. However, when it starts to get complex I have to use AutharizationService class with Custom IAuthorizationRequirement and Handler implementations and all the configurations related to them. That's what I don't like about it. Also, I'm planning to use mongoDB for my app so I don't want to deal with Identity Store problems. Also Identity creates all the fields in your DB even if you don't need them and again you have to configure all these things. I've once chosen the Identity path I think I should try the other path for once as well :)

Comment: I would listen to Robert. I have seen authorization systems try to work at the business layer and they are problematic. The UI needs to know the business rules because it decides what features to make visible to begin with. If you put it in the business layer, you may end up with a page that displays beautifully but just raises an error when you try to perform a privileged operation-- that's not really acceptable-- so you end up replicating the authorization checks at the UI layer anyway. The modern way to do it with claims, visible to both, which is how Identity works.

Answer (score -1):

'It seems like this framework adds lots of overhead"

It doesn't. You can use your custom login method, probably User.Login or similar to create a claims identity using your own logic. It's a great and fast infrastructure if you get rid of EF. It also allows to easily switch authentication if needed.

"The UI needs to know the business rules because it decides what features to make visible to begin with. "

Thou shalt not trust GUI developers, they are evil ;)